# How to push items in to an array which was referenced in collections schema in mongoose, nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i want to create an item and push it into items array which was referenced in my collections schema. What i am sending in the payload is item properties and collection id. But i am getting CastError. Please help

**COLLECTION SCHEMA**

```
const collectionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, require: true, ref: "Item" }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default model("Collection", collectionSchema);
```

**ITEM SCHEMA**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;

const itemSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    likes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    collections: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Collection" },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
export default model("Item", itemSchema);
```

**CREATE ITEM ROUTE**

```
itemRouter.post("/", JWTAuthMiddleware, async (req, res, next) => {
    const item = new ItemModal(req.body)
    const collection = await CollectionModal.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.user._id,
      {
        $push : { items: [{ ...req.body, id: item._id }] },
      },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.send(collection);
});
```

What i am getting is an CASTERROR
[image]

Comment: Can you try to push as ; $push : { items: item }

Comment: i got the error. Actually i was passing authorized user id instead of collection id as a first argument. it worked now. Thank u btw